# Attaching information per file and commit in git

Tags: git, version-control

How would I attach some information per single file and commit in
git?

My use case is as follows:

I am used to assign "quality levels" to specific files of a
project - like "complete", "checked", "reviewed".  Let's stick
with "checked" for the rest of this question.  Let's further
assume my project consists of files A, B, and C.  Finally, let's
use plain two-digit, increasing numbers to identify commits.

---

In the beginning of the project, none of the files is checked.
At commit 03, I decide that A is worth getting a "checked", so we
have:

| File | Checked | Recent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 03 | 03 |
| B |  | 03 |
| C |  | 03 |

Column "Checked" denotes the commit when a file got checked,
column "Recent" denotes the most recent commit that touched a
file.

---

Work continues to commit 05, now C gets checked:

| File | Checked | Recent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 03 | 04 |
| B |  | 05 |
| C | 05 | 05 |

(Please note that file A got modified by commit 04!)

---

At this point I'd like to have a report about the current check
status of my project, with the following outcome:

```
! A (03 -> 04)
- B
= C
```

Meaning:

- Differences from commit 03 to 04 are unchecked in A
- B is completely unchecked
- C is completely checked

---

I review the diffs on file A from commit 03 to 04, find some
typo, fix the typo, commit the change, and mark the new commit 06
"checked" on A, resulting in the following picture:

| File | Checked | Recent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 06 | 06 |
| B |  | 05 |
| C | 05 | 05 |

and in the following report:

```
= A
- B
= C
```

In CVS, tags can be (ab)used to achieve such a per-file quality
reporting.  In git, I have been using side-car files per project
that track quality status per file and commit, but that feels
awkward and is quite some overhead to maintain.

So how could this be achieved in git in a more natural way?

Comment: what you need is a code review platform, not git.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes

Comment: @BagusTesa: I need git as VCS.  Any tool on top of git that fulfills my requirements and that has a decent CLI would be a candidate.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Had a look at git notes.  I've been hoping for something more porcelain-ish and less heavy-weight, but so far this seems to be my best option.

Comment: Git tags are capable of tagging any object. It's nearly always used for tagging commits, but files are legal too. So you can create an "A-reviewed" tag to remember the most recent version of A that has been reviewed. Note however that lightweight tags are not versioned, so you won't be able to ask "Who reviewed A v5?" or "When was A v5 reviewed?" or "What was the most recently reviewed version of A as of the start of the fiscal year?"

Answer (score 1):

In git universe you achieve this with branches and pull requests.

| File | Checked | Recent | Git universe |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 03 | 04 | File in a topic (feature) branch |
| B |  | 05 | File in a topic (feature) branch |
| C | 05 | 05 | File has been merged into an important branch (often called `main`) |

Which version of the file has been reviewed doesn't need to be explicitly recorded because differences are seen during the merge process. The merge process is often is done via a Pull Request process provided by a tool running on top of git (Azure DevOps, GitLab, GitHub, BitBucket etc.)

Please note you may have multiple levels of maturity of a code change. For example: `featureX`->`develop`->`main`.

Git is very flexible in supporting different branching strategies; there are few popular established branching strategies each with its benefits and pain points.

Since you're new to git you may benefit from using an established workflow rather than invent your own. Here are few popular names:

1. Git Flow
2. GitHub Flow
3. GitLab Flow